# How to create a dependency graph of components in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, dependencies, handlebars.js, dependency-graph

I'm trying to navigate through a large Ember project and would like to create a visual graph of the component tree.

Is there a way to parse a `.hbs` file and create a dependency graph of the components and sub-components in it?

Is there a way to do the same for an Ember route?

**What I've found**

- I've found `dependency-cruiser` but not sure how it could work to parse through .hbs files https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser

Comment: if your app in compatible with embroider in strict mode, you could probably pass the output of the stage 2 transformation to dependency-cruiser library -- it converts everything to js with imports and all that

Comment: so it would be able to convert the .hbs files to js as well?

Comment: Correct, and v2 addons do this as well!

Comment: dope gonna give that a shot! thanks!